# Ecto: Custom binary_id

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have an Ecto model that I want to be stored in the database with a custom binary_id generated from an elixir function. Is this possible?

My id function looks like this:

```
def gen_id
    String.upcase to_string Enum.take_random('abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz123456789', 8)
end
```

My schema looks like this:

```
schema "orders" do
    belongs_to :type, Invoicer.Customer
    @primary_key {:id, :binary_id, autogenerate: true}
    field :order_details, :string

    timestamps()
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should implement your own type following the [`Ecto.Type`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Type.html) behaviour.

Within that type, you can add an `autogenerate/0` function, which is your `gen_id` function, to generate the id for you.

To see a completed example of something like this, you can take a look at [`Ecto.UUID`](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/blob/master/lib/ecto/uuid.ex) which has everything you are asking for here.